# SQL Selecting based off largest date from different table

Tags: sql

I am attempting to write a query that pulls Order information from various tables. I have hit a road block at the target date value.

It seems that every time a target date is changed a new row is added in that table. All I want is to be able to select only the newest Target Date. What should I do?

```
 select Distinct
 OR01001 AS OrderNumber,
 OR01002 AS OrderType,
 OR01003 AS CustomerCode,
 OR01015 AS OrderDate,
 OR01017 AS CustomerREP,
 OR01018 AS ContactPerson,
 OR01019 AS SalesmanNumber,
 OR03011 - OR03012 AS OpenQuantity,
 SC03003 AS StockBalance,
 OR01050 AS WarehouseNumber,
 OR01072 AS CustomerPO,
 OR03005 AS ItemCode,
 OR03002 AS LineNumber,
 OR500100.OR50004 As TargetDate
 from OR010100
 INNER Join OR030100 ON OR030100.OR03001 = OR010100.OR01001
 INNER Join SL010100 ON SL010100.SL01001 = OR010100.OR01003
 INNER Join SC030100 ON SC030100.SC03001 = OR030100.OR03005 
 Inner JOIN OR500100 ON OR500100.OR50001 = OR010100.OR01001 
 where OR010100.OR01002 <> 0 AND OR010100.OR01002 <> 6 AND OR01017 = 'SLOTT' 
 Order by OR01017 ASC;
```

Comment: If I were you, I would quit before you go crazy having to work with table names and field names as inscrutable as those.

Comment: Unfortunately this database Schema is the way it is. It was designed to be used in multiple languages 15 years ago.

Comment: scala schema, good guess

Comment: Are you looking for the maximum target date overall or the maximum that meets the conditions in the WHERE clause?  Also, what database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your columns correctly, here's one way:

```
SELECT ...,
    OR500100A.OR50004 AS TargetDate
FROM ...
INNER JOIN OR500100 AS OR500100A ON OR500100A.OR50001 = OR010100.OR01001 
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM OR500100 AS OR500100B 
                   WHERE OR500100B.OR5001 = OR010100.OR01001 
                   AND OR500100B.OR50004 > OR500100A.OR50004)
...
```

This makes sure you only get one `OR500100` row with the latest value in `OR50004` for the given `OR5001`.

Answer (score 1):

from what i understand,

```
SELECT
...
MAX(OR500100.OR50004) As TargetDate
FROM...
WHERE...
GROUP BY --everything but OR500100.OR50004
ORDER BY...
```

should do the trick

EDIT: ty Ic.

Comment: +1 If the OP's query is not selecting anything else from `OR500100` this should also work. Although I think you mean to GROUP BY *everything except `OR500100.OR50004`*...